# All actions getting forwarded to the Struts2 servlet after URL rewriting

Tags: java, regex, struts2

I am using struts 2 and I recently configured my `web.xml` and `struts.xml` to change the eliminate `.action` from the url. Gladly everything is working fine except for a major issue.
I want some of my request to get forwarded to other servlets but the following code ensures that my every action is redirected to the Struts2 servlet.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

I want to forward my `"/do/*"` to a different servlet say `xyz` then can someone help me with what should I do. I have an idea that I might have to use regex but I have tried many patterns and failed. I have tried the best regex that I think should match :

```
[^(\/do\/*)]

    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>

</filter-mapping>



<servlet>
    <servlet-name>xyzServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.blah.xyzServiceImpl</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>xyzServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/do/guide</url-pattern>
```

Similarly I have many such servlets who have there own purpose. url pattern is almost same for them ... they are like /do/abc or /do/pqr etc.

EDIT : ISSUE SOLVED by using StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter and adding the accepted solution to the code.

Comment: What URL you are trying to hit which gets directed to struts2.

Comment: Moreover you are using a filter , and this filter declaration will listen to all requests.

Comment: any url that start with "/do/" ... to be more generic : "/do/*" for this I tried a regex in the above code replacing <url-pattern> with ^[\/do\/*] instead of /* but it didn't quite work out.

Comment: I know that /* will redirect every url to Struts2 servlet. I want to avoid that. That's my purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure your URL in exclude pattern as like below in struts.xml. And add a servlet mapping for /do/* in web.xml.

```
<constant name="struts.action.excludePattern" value="/do/.*" />
```

Comment: I see what you did there... quite simple but I don't know for what reason this thing is not working ... its still not processing the request... are you sure that once a request is excluded by the struts it will be forwarded down the filter to the web services servlets?

Comment: yes, It will work. I myself used it in a project. It still working fine. Whats the error did you got ? Is the URL still handled by struts ?

Comment: See to be precise I have a set of filters for various purposes after which comes a set of web Services servlets. the thing is that everything is getting forwarded to struts2 and web.xml is excluding it  and then it is coming back to struts.xml as you are saying. but then my request is getting a 404 for Network Error which is very much imo because the request is not finding a proper servlet that could serve.

Comment: if your getting 404 means Struts is not handling the request. There might be other reason for not reaching the servlet code. servlet mapping or order of the URL mapping might be wrong. Please share the web.xml configuration here.

Comment: Also struts is not suppose to handle it. And prior to making changes to shed .action from URL the FilterDispatcher was handling only *.action request. Then too these request were getting processed. That's why I am skeptical whether after excluding the particular pattern the request is dropped or is it sent back to web.xml to find a suitor?

Comment: No, struts will not drop the request. It will just call filterChain.doFilter to process next filter in the chain.

Comment: Okay but in my chaining the Struts2 filter is the last filter... which means it will stop filtering after that. Makes sense that it will not filter after that. But then will it go to the servlet coming out of the filter chain?

Comment: I think there is a problem with excludePattern. I configured its value with .* and still my every page is opening which means its not getting rightly configured.

Answer (score 0):

M.G.Manikandan solution is better, I'm keeping this Filter Based solution just in case. The idea it to create a new filter on top of the Struts Filter (Must go before the Struts filter when you declare it on the web.xml)

```
    public class CustomFilter implements Filter {
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;

        if(request!=null){      
            //optimize this if needed
            if(request.getServletPath().toLowerCase().indexOf("/do/")>-1){                  
                if(!res.isCommitted())
                    request.getRequestDispatcher(request.getServletPath()).forward(request, res);
            } else {            
                chain.doFilter(req, res);
            }
        }
    }       
    public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {}
    public void destroy() {}      
}
```

and the in web.xml

```
    <filter>
        <filter-name>CustomFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
            com.mypackage.CustomFilter
        </filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CustomFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Comment: One thing more... I think the purpose this class is serving is served by URLRewriteFilter too I suppose.. Can't we go about adding a rule or two in the urlRewrite.xml?

Comment: If you chain or forward when needed you could use the URLRewriteFilter